# LibreOffice Writer Macros

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-writer

Is there any way to record macro in LibreOffice Writer to save the file as pdf? On a daily basis, I have multiple files that I save as a pdf and would like to save time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Macro recording does not produce good code.  Instead, adapt from the following answer: [LibreOffice Calc macro: How to export cell range to PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509532/libreoffice-calc-macro-how-to-export-cell-range-to-pdf-file)

However, it does not sound like a macro is needed.  Use the `--convert-to` command line parameter as described at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/.